# Regex Assistance needed (Powershell)

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a text output similar to this:

```
svwxchmig101.vmx:111:sched.mem.min = "0"
svwxchmig101.vmx:112:sched.mem.minSize = "0"
TEAMWIKI.vmx:114:sched.mem.min = "0"
TEAMWIKI.vmx:115:sched.mem.minSize = "0"
XenTemplateWin2008.vmx:93:sched.mem.min = "0"
XenTemplateWin2008.vmx:94:sched.mem.minSize = "0"
Zenith_TalismaWIN2K12R2STD_10-13-15.vmx:103:sched.mem.min = "0"
Zenith_TalismaWIN2K12R2STD_10-13-15.vmx:104:sched.mem.minSize = "0"`
```

I need a regex to be used in powershell that will capture three groups as it iterates on each line:

First group captures everything up to the first colon (not including the colon).

Second group captures 'sched.mem.min' or 'sched.mem.minSize'.

Third group captures number value between quotes. While the example code above shows all of them to be zero, it also could be a non-zero value (4096, 32768, etc).

After hours of looking at examples here, I simply can't figure out how to make a single regex that will do all three captures.

Comment: Lets get specific with the requirements - is it *always* `sched.mem.minSize` and `sched.mem.min` or (as I expect) is it actually `anything.something.whatever` - is it *always* three parts, or..... Is the thing in quotes  always numeric or could it also be `"foo"`?

Comment: I'm using select-string to pull just 'sched.mem.min' and 'sched.mem.minSize' so yes it is always those two.

Comment: This is the latest I just came with, which seems to work:  

`(\S*\.vmx)|(sched.\w*.\w*.\w)|"(.+)"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
^(.*?):.*?(sched.mem.min|sched.mem.minSize).*"(\d+)"$
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Answer (score 0):

Having made the comment above with respect to providing complete information, I'll note that you don't need regex for the problem as you've outlined it. Assuming that the file is called "Data.txt"...

```
$Data = Get-Content Data.txt
ForEach ($Line in $Data) {
    $Groups = $Line -split ":"
    $Group1 = $Groups[0]
    $Group2and3 = $Groups[-1]
    $Grps = $Group2and3 -split "="
    $Group2 = $Grps[0].Trim()
    $Group3 = $Grps[1].Trim()
# Do something with $Group1 and $Group2 and $Group3 here
}
```

Comment: This could actually be simplified and several lines combined, but in this form, it's clearer and doesn't rely on any "idiom"s except that negative indices to arrays count from the end of the array.

Comment: Incidentally, you are using regex twice in your answer which "doesn't need regex" ..

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler How so?

Comment: The parameters to `-split` are regexes - in this case, ones which match one character ;-) . You need to use the .Net `.Split()` string method to split on literal characters. It would matter if you tried to split something where the separator was a regex special character, e.g.  `'a(b' -split '('`

Comment: Hmmm... I'd gotten the impression that it was the other way around. OK, I'll do some reading.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this *regex* `([^:]+).*?(sched\.mem.min(?:Size)?).*?`:

[image]
**Script:**

```
Get-Content "yourLog.txt" | ForEach-Object { 
    $result = [regex]::Match($_, '([^:]+).*?(sched\.mem.min(?:Size)?).*?"([^"]+)"')
    #$result.Groups[1].Value
    #$result.Groups[2].Value
    #$result.Groups[3].Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like regex and everything, but "I chose a tool I can't use" doesn't make for a good question. You don't need regex to split a string in PowerShell:

```
$test = @'
svwxchmig101.vmx:111:sched.mem.min = "0"
svwxchmig101.vmx:112:sched.mem.minSize = "0"
TEAMWIKI.vmx:114:sched.mem.min = "0"
TEAMWIKI.vmx:115:sched.mem.minSize = "0"
XenTemplateWin2008.vmx:93:sched.mem.min = "0"
XenTemplateWin2008.vmx:94:sched.mem.minSize = "0"
Zenith_TalismaWIN2K12R2STD_10-13-15.vmx:103:sched.mem.min = "0"
Zenith_TalismaWIN2K12R2STD_10-13-15.vmx:104:sched.mem.minSize = "0"
'@ -split "`r?`n"   # setup, you would use Get-Content


$test | ForEach-Object {

    $Name, $Mem, [int]$Num = $_.split(':= "')[0,2,6]

    $Name, $Mem, $Num
}
```

example output:

```
XenTemplateWin2008.vmx
sched.mem.minSize
0
Zenith_TalismaWIN2K12R2STD_10-13-15.vmx
sched.mem.min
0
```

Comment: Don't care much for smug attitudes. But since you feel it necessary to start your answer that way I'll return the favor. Not explaining what your code is doing doesn't make for a good answer either.

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking this. Here's a regex that works for what I want to do:

```
(\S*\.vmx)|(sched.\w*.\w*.\w)|"(.+)
```